# How to ensure a MySql connection through Tomcat 8?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, tomcat8

I have a webapp that is running properly in Tomcat without the database.

If I add the following to tomcat context.xml it seems to kill the whole server, I get a blank page and connection refused for my app and the tomcat manager app:

```
<Context docBase="${catalina.base}/webapps/ROOT.war">
    <Parameter name="application.properties" value="/home/users/tomcat/application.properties"/>
</Context>
```

There is an `application.properties` file in `/home/users/tomcat/` which is the same user that runs tomcat. So how come this line is bringing my server down?

MySQL 5.5 is running and the properties file I used is:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springboot
spring.datasource.username=automation
spring.datasource.password=xxxxxxxxxxxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#comment out below line to create schema on new database
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

How do I troubleshoot the database connectivity?

I know mysql is configured for port 3306 and it will let me login with the details in that file, if I use SSH.

Comment: what is this `Parameter name` thing? First time I see something like this.

Comment: I found that in a guide, I will try and find the exact link. But if that is not correct, what is the correct method to point to the location of the properties file in the tomcat home directory?

Comment: what is the correct method to point to the location of the properties file in the tomcat home directory?